# angular 5 routing from auxiliary children route to parent gives match error

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I have added a second router outlet for 'reports' and this router outlet is in the "layout" component for reports. All three children routes are linked to in a 'sub menu' component and my issue arises when I go back to the 'start route' (assignment list), thats where i get

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'SE_556354-3353/%2Freports'
>   Error

How do I get back to the "root"/parent (assignmentlist) ? Basically, just how can I jump between these links?

Here is the relevant code.

app.module

```
const routes = [
{ path: ':orgNoParam/organizational-unit/:unitIdParam/employments', component: EmployeeComponent },
 {
    path: ':orgNoParam/reports', component: ReportsComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: AssignmentListComponent, outlet: 'content' },
        { path: 'managers', component: AssignmentCompactManagersComponent, outlet: 'content' },
        { path: 'employments', component: AssignmentCompactEmployeesComponent, outlet: 'content' }
    ]
 }
];
```

reportsComponent (aka "the layout")

```
<div id="assignment">
<assignment-submenu></assignment-submenu>
<div>
    <!--angular error messages-->
    <error-message *ngIf="errorList?.length" [errorList]="errorList"></error-message>
</div>

<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

Submenu.html (this is where the links are)

```
<ul class="sub-menu" *ngIf="tempList && tempList.length">
<li *ngFor="let translation of tempList">

    <ng-container *ngIf="translation.link=='reports'">
        <a class="new-style" (click)="goToRoot()">{{ translation.name }}</a>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="translation.link=='managers' || translation.link=='employments'">
        <a class="new-style" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { content: [translation.link] } }]">{{ translation.name }}</a>
    </ng-container>

</li>
```

Submenu.ts

```
goToRoot() {
    this.router.navigate([this.orgNoParam, '/reports']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved itby setting the routerlink to 'routerLink="{{translation.link}}"' for the "root"-child, and then setting the path of the "root"-child (it has the path '') to '../reports' and voila.